# flow intersection type incompatible with $Diff<>

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Given this flow typed JS file, the last line errors, but the second-last line is fine. Shouldn't the type of `A & B` be the same as the difference of `A & B & C` and `C`?

```
/* @flow */

type A = {
  a: true,
};
type B = {
  b: true,
};
type C = {
  c: true,
};

const diff1: $Diff<A & B & C, C> = {a: true, b: true};

// error with incompatible types
const diff2: $Diff<A & B & C, C> = ({a: true, b: true} : A & B);
```

Comment: Is this related to typescript at all besides the presence of types? I'm fairly sure this is just a flowtype question.

Comment: Removed the typescript tag. Looks like TypeScript has no exclusionary typing that flow has with $Diff.

Comment: This looks like it's fixed: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN6phgCGAXGBgE4CueANKgL4DcmuBAEKkKVMACMGzNp1798YAMIjK1AMZTWHbn1Rq4AOwDOGMABMAllCgBGBgBIAIlagAeYgDIwwr4vZKAPhV6Ri1-SVC2OVRgYDA8JiY4JjAECwwACzALA30AWxwaDAtxGAJsfCM9QxNzFwAmB2drdzAvHyV-RSCyAApyEOkOCU0osAZPbwBKHiA